# get list of images from s3 bucket using .net core

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to display some selected images in front end of my application( angular).

How can I get selected images from an S3 bucket using .net core API?

Which is better: To get the image or the image URL from the S3 bucket using .net core API and give it to the front end part(angular)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please clarify your question? For example, what do you mean by "get selected images"? What is your front-end application -- is it a web app, a mobile app, etc? Are you wanting to simply display an image within a web page? Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: edited my post thanks john

Comment: You might also want to improve the title to get more people looking at your Question.

Comment: Security wise it would be better to definitely fetch via the .NET Core API side. You could use pre-signed URLs but they have a limited lifetime.

Comment: Glenn how to fetch selected multiple preassigned URLs at once in .net core??